# How do I write a Rails finder method that will return the greatest date grouped by record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 with PostGres 9.5.  I have a table that tracks prices ...

```
                                         Table "public.crypto_prices"
       Column       |            Type             |                         Modifiers
--------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                     | not null default nextval('crypto_prices_id_seq'::regclass)
 crypto_currency_id | integer                     |
 market_cap_usd     | bigint                      |
 total_supply       | bigint                      |
 last_updated       | timestamp without time zone |
 created_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at         | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

I would like to get the latest price per currency (where `last_updated` is greatest) for a select currencies.  I can find all the prices related to certain currencies like so

```
current_prices = CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: CryptoIndexCurrency.all.pluck(:crypto_currency_id).uniq)
```

Then I can sort them by currency into arrays, looping through each until I find the one with the greatest `last_updated` value, but **how can I write a finder that will return exactly one row per currency with the greatest `last_updated` date?**

**Edit:** Tried Owl Max's suggestion like so

```
ids = CryptoIndexCurrency.all.pluck(:crypto_currency_id).uniq
crypto_price_ids = CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: ids).group(:crypto_currency_id).maximum(:last_updated).keys
puts "price ids: #{crypto_price_ids.length}"
@crypto_prices = CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: crypto_price_ids)
puts "ids: #{@crypto_prices.size}"
```

Although the first "puts" only reveals a size of "12" the second puts reveals over 38,000 results.  It should only be returning 12 results, one for each currency.

Comment: Just throwing out a thought - Have you considered ordering by` last_updated` and grabbing the first instance?

Comment: That would only return one result, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you want more than one, you can do something like `.first(3)` for 3 (fill in whatever number).

Comment: That's not what I mean.  I only what the latest price per currency for certain currencies (e.g. crypto_currency_id values I specify).  Where would I speicfy the specific IDs using "first(3)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only works with Rails5 because of [`or`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) query method

```
specific_ids = CryptoIndexCurrency.distinct.pluck(:crypto_currency_id)
hash = CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: specific_ids)
                  .group(:crypto_currency_id)
                  .maximum(:last_updated)
hash.each_with_index do |(k, v), i|
  if i.zero?
    res = CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: k, last_updated: v)
  else
    res.or(CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: k, last_updated: v))
  end
end
```

**Explanation**:

You can use [`group`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) to regroup all your `CryptoPrice` object by each `CryptoIndexCurrency` presents in your table.

Then using [`maximum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-maximum) (thanks to @artgb) to take the biggest value `last_updated`. This will output a `Hash` with keys: `crypto_currency_id` and value 
 `last_updated`.

Finally, you can use `keys` to only get an `Array` of `crypto_currency_id`.

```
CryptoPrice.group(:crypto_currency_id).maximum(:last_updated)
=> => {2285=>2017-06-06 09:06:35 UTC,
       2284=>2017-05-18 15:51:05 UTC,
       2267=>2016-03-22 08:02:53 UTC}
```

**The problem with this solution is that you get the maximum date for each row without getting the whole records.**

To get the the records, you can do a loop on the hash pairwise. with `crypto_currency_id` and  `last_updated`. It's hacky but the only solution I found.

Comment: Thanks.  Here you're finding the latest price for every currency, but what I was going for was only get teh latest price for certain currencies (e.g. "where  crypto_currency_id in (ids)").  How would I add that condition into what you have listed?

Comment: Just add a `where` clause before `group`ing ! e.g `CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: specific_ids). group(:crypto_currency_id).maximum(:last_updated).keys` it will do the same thing, except it will not take in account the `CryptoIndexCurrency` you don't need.

Comment: I edited my question to include your suggestion.  THis line "@crypto_prices = CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: crypto_price_ids)" is returning tens of thousands of results, which is incorrect.  It shoudl only be returning one result per currency.

Comment: I think it's because your table allows to have multiple rows with the same `crypto_currency_id`. That mean you have to select `cryptoprice.id` and not only `crypto_currency_id` whithin the group. I will show you an example in few hours! You are close to the solution.

Comment: @Dave very nice question! I think I found a solution but it's hacky, let me know if it works, if it doesn't, I'm sorry but that mean I'm not good enough to find a solution and I will stop trying ^^

Answer (score 1):

We can write a finder that will return exactly one row per currency with the greatest last_updated date in such a way like

```
current_prices = CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: CryptoIndexCurrency.all.pluck(:crypto_currency_id).uniq).select("*, id as crypto_price_id, MAX(last_updated) as last_updated").group(:crypto_currency_id)
```

I hope that this will took you closer to your goal. Thank you.

Comment: When I run this I get the error, "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "crypto_prices.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: Can you please give it a try by updating select by `("*, id as crypto_price_id, MAX(last_updated) as last_updated")`. 
I have also read somewhere that we also need to explicitly specify ordering too in case of PG. So if above solution doesn't workout for you, also add ordering clause, that may help out. Thank You.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that would generate the answer.  I'm unclear about what you want me to do.

Comment: unfortunately, this query does not work with postgreSQL, you need to include the id in the aggregate function like `.group(:crypto_currency_id, :id)` but then you don't have anymore unique crypto_currency_ids.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can fetch the latest updated row here from particular table.

```
  CryptoPrice.order(:updated_at).pluck(:updated_at).last
```

This Should be help for you.

Comment: THis only returns one row always, right?  Also you're not taking account of the fact taht I only want to return the latest price for certain currencies (identified by the ids in my question)

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not easy to do in Rails in one statement/query. If you don't mind using multiple statements/queries than this is your solution:

```
cc_ids = CryptoIndexCurrency.distinct.pluck(:crypto_currency_id)

result = cc_ids.map do |cc_id|
  max_last_updated = CryptoPrice.where(crypto_currency_id: cc_id).maximum(:last_updated)
  CryptoPrice.find_by(crypto_currency_id: cc_id, last_updated: max_last_updated)
end
```

The result of the `map` method is what you are looking for. This produces 2 queries for every `crypto_currency_id` and 1 query to request the `crypto_currency_id`s.

If you want to do this with one query you'll need to use `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)`. More info on this in the following links:

- [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql
- https://blog.codeship.com/folding-postgres-window-functions-into-rails/

But in this scenario you'll have to write some SQL.

EDIT 1:

If you want a nice `Hash` result run:

```
cc_ids.zip(result).to_h
```

EDIT 2:

If you want to halve the amount of queries you can shove the `max_last_updated` query in the `find_by` as sub-query like so:

```
cc_ids = CryptoIndexCurrency.distinct.pluck(:crypto_currency_id)

result = cc_ids.map do |cc_id|
  CryptoPrice.find_by(<<~SQL.squish)
    crypto_currency_id = #{cc_id} AND last_updated = (
      SELECT MAX(last_updated) 
      FROM crypto_prices 
      WHERE crypto_currency_id = #{cc_id})
  SQL
end
```

This produces 1 queries for every `crypto_currency_id` and 1 query to request the `crypto_currency_id`s.

Comment: I don't mind running multiple statements, but how many queries is this generating?  I want to minimize the number of queries.

Comment: 2 queries per `crypto_currency_id` + 1 for fetching the `crypto_currency_ids`. Keep in mind that the query to fetch `max_last_updated ` only returns 1 value and `CryptoPrice.find_by(crypto_currency_id: cc_id, last_updated: max_last_updated)` only returns one record. There is never a whole set of records initialized in Rails. If you want to know the exact number of queries, run: `CryptoIndexCurrency.distinct.pluck(:crypto_currency_id).count * 2 + 1`

Comment: Thanks but I think Owl max's solution only has 2 queries -- one to get the IDs and anotehr to get the data .

Comment: That's correct, keep in mind that he doesn't fetch `crypto_currency_id` from `CryptoIndexCurrency`. If your `CryptoPrice` table contains `nil` values, or values not present in `CryptoIndexCurrency` those will be returned as well.

Comment: @JohanWentholt, you are right, I skipped the first `where` clause in the first query because I though it was not necessary to understand the idea. But you are right it add another query. I'm sure the solution is possible to write in one query, but I'm not sure it is possible with rails ORM (in POSTGRESQL anyway, it is possible in MySQL for sure). I think Vakiliy approches is the best that far. I haven't test the query but writing this is row SQL is a good idea. Your idea is good too but not scalable on huge DB because it produces N+1 query problem.